# Print QGraphicsScene on multiply pages

Tags: qt, printing, qt5

I have such code:

```
QPrinter printer;
if (QPrintDialog(&printer).exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    QPainter painter(&printer);
    scene->render(&painter, QRectF(0, 0, 10000, 10000), QRectF(0, 0, 1024, 1024), Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
}
```

I expect that content of scene will be zoomed and printed on multiply pages. Zoom works fine, but pdf file (i use pdf printer) contains only 1 page: zoomed left upper corner of scene.

Qt 5.15. Qt += printsupport option in project file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multipage printing, you have to manage things by yourself.

Here is the code I use:

```
void printScene(QGraphicsScene* scene, qreal pageHeight, QPrinter& printer, int pageCount)
{
    if (scene)
    {
        if (pageCount < 1)
        {
            LOG_WARNING() << QString("invalid page count: %1. Defaulting to 1").arg(pageCount);
            pageCount = 1;
        }

        QRectF pageRect(0, 0, scene->sceneRect().width(), pageHeight);
        qreal  paperHeight = scene->sceneRect().height();

        QPainter painter(&printer);

        for (int page = 0; page < pageCount; ++page)
        {
            scene->render(&painter, QRectF(), pageRect);

            paperHeight -= pageHeight;
            pageRect.translate(0, pageHeight);
            pageRect.setHeight(qMin(pageHeight, paperHeight));

            if ((page + 1) < pageCount)
                printer.newPage();
        }
    }
    else
        LOG_ERROR() << ("attempt to print a null scene");
}
```